# Eclipse - black background in javadoc popup

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, tooltip, javadoc

I am using Elementary OS, based on Ubuntu 12.04 and Eclipse Luna.
The background color of javadoc popups is black and font color is dark grey, so it is unreadable. 
I tried to change background in eclipse preferences, but it did not change.
Then I used google, and found solution, that I need to change tooltip bg color. So I did it. But still no change.
Anyone knows how to change that color ?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04 and Eclipse Mars. I solved the problem by adding the following lines in eclipse.ini :

> --launcher.GTK_version
>   2

Comment: There's a bug somewhere between Eclipse and SWT which should be solved in Oxygen. This workaround is the only thing we have on linux so far...

Comment: At least in Eclipse 4.6M6 Oxygen the javadoc hovers are still not displayed properly. The javadoc view and normal popup colors can be changed, but when during code completion a hover window is opened, a secondary popup with the javadoc information for each potential completion is display with the wrong colors. Using above option fixes that.

Answer (score 1):

As a KDE user, you have to change the tooltip background color with **System Settings**. Navigate to

**Application Apperearence -> Colors (Left side menu) -> Colors (Colors tab on right side)**

and adjust the **Tooltip Background** and **Tooltip Text** colors. In your case, adjusting the tooltip background should be enough.

The setting is under GNOME UBUNTU in Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I would get a blank assist popup window and if I clicked on the window it would turn black and not show any text.
I tried many things to get the text to show up like changing the eclipse foreground and back ground colors or the above system settings.
I then started to look at the VcXsrv X server program I was running to display on my windows box.
I turned off the 'Native opengl' in the 'Extra Settings' screen of the XLaunch program.
This fixed my problem.