# Eclipse content assist flyout shows unreadable dark on black despite using a light theme

Tags: eclipse

Starting to use Eclipse 2018-12, the code preview flyout from content-assist has an unreadable foreground/background combination as in the following screen shot:

[image]

I found the Appearance->Color and Fonts->Content Assist preference, but this only takes care of the right part shown above with the white backgrond. <strike>(Similarly, if I hover over an element in the editor, the tooltip is also some unreadable dark color on black background.)</strike>

This is on Ubuntu. In my active theme I find

```
@define-color theme_tooltip_bg_color #fbeaa0;
```

which is clearly not black. The hint about tooltip comes from some of the ultra-old answers like https://superuser.com/a/198589/345087, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38135826/2954288, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3572010/2954288, https://askubuntu.com/a/101913/367444, but these don't seem to apply anymore.

Does anyone know how to fix this with the most recent Eclipse release?

EDIT: I should add that the black window is shown only for Template Proposals Java/Java Type/Java Non Type Proposals are all good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Window > Preferences: General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts* you have to change the color *Basic > **Information background color***, not the *Basic > Content Assist background color* for that.

Only in Java templates, this preference is not used probably due to a bug in Eclipse 2018-12. <strike>Please report it to [Eclipse JDT](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT&component=UI&version=4.10).</strike> Thanks for reporting it to Eclipse (as [Eclipse bug 543110](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=543110)).

Comment: To bad, but this applies only to my comment about the "hover over java element", which can indeed be changed this way.

Comment: It works for me for the black area that is shown in your screenshot not only for infos shown on hover. Does it work with a new workspace?

Comment: No, even in a fresh workspace with no settings changed, the template information bit keeps its black background.

Comment: @Harald That looks to me like a bug that hasn't been reported yet (see my edited answer).

Answer (score 1):

Window > Preferences: General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts

Set the javadoc background to white - // discovered on photon through experimentation